# Android async task not loading

Tags: android

I am using the following code

```
class AddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
     {      
        ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {      
     dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());         
    dialog.setMessage("Loading"); 
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);         
    dialog.setCancelable(false);      
    dialog.show();

      }     
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) 
    {     

//task
return(null);  


    }     

      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
     {     
        dialog.dismiss();    
     }  

     }
```

I am calling it from here

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AddTask.execute();
}
```

Logcat

03-29 18:16:06.434: E/AndroidRuntime(1246): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Why You have put **return(null);** in doInBackground Instead of that can just try **return null;**. I am not sure but you just Quick try and check above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you got exception due to this line

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

plz use **this** instead of getApplicationContext() or you can also use **YourActivity.this** for solve this issue.

Comment: @Ajay-Yes that works. But i dont understand why. In my case getApplicationContext() should be the same as this right

Comment: I think this would mean is that getApplicationContext returns a context which is for the application itself and not the activity, while “this” would give you the context of the activity in which you are creating the dialog. I think since it is the activity which is associated with the UI (and for whom the window has been created), using the application context would have caused the crash here. and for info visit http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11199

Answer (score 2):

You should attach an activity to your asynk task like:

```
AddTask(Activity activity){  
    mActivity  = activity;  
}   
protected void onPreExecute()   
{        
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);           
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");   
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);           
    dialog.setCancelable(false);        
    dialog.show();  
}    
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)  
{  
    if(mActivity != null)       
        dialog.dismiss();      
}   
public void unbind(){  
    mActivity = null;  
}
```

and call unbind in onDestroy of your activity

Answer (score 1):

Can not use `getApplicationContext()` get the context, and must use the Activity, so to solve the following

like

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);         
dialog.setMessage("Loading"); 
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);         
dialog.setCancelable(false);      
dialog.show();
```